# How to update python gui?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to update my gui every second (i dont actually care about the time, but it should be like realtime). I got a script, where actually a Label as an int should increase by one and displayed. But i don't get the change, also i want to place the Label according to the width of the root, but it doesn't update. Only the update is a problem, maybe someone can help me with that. (Im a Beginner-Noob).

Script:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

c = 0
root = Tk()
root.title("Real Time Plot")
root.minsize(width = 200, height = 300)
m = root.winfo_reqwidth() / 2

root.update()
Text = Label(root, text = c)
Text.place(x =m, y = 150)
c = c + 1
print(m)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to use a Python Threading, which will carry out this **flawlessly!**

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time

def realtime_update():
    while True:
        global c, Text
        c += 1
        Text.configure(text=c+1)
        time.sleep(0.001)
        root_width = root.winfo_geometry()
        root_width = root_width.split('x')
        root_width = int(root_width[0])

        Text.place(x=root_width/2, y=150)
        time.sleep(0.01)

c = 0
root = Tk()
root.title("Real Time Plot")
root.minsize(width = 200, height = 300)
m = root.winfo_reqwidth() / 2

Text = Label(root, text = c)
Text.place(x=int(m), y = 150)
print(m)
threading.Thread(target=realtime_update, daemon=True).start()
root.mainloop()
```

It solves the following:

1. Realtime Update (precision to 0.01s)
2. Label changes position when root window resizes

Answer (score 0):

I've created a timer so I suppose you can do it like I did. Hope this works for you.

First, create a StringVar:

text = StringVar (value = "text")

Then create a Label with textvariable.
yourlabel  =  Label(root, textvariable = Text)

And then just make a function that will update the yourlabel:
yourlabel.set(and here you pass the new value)

So then your yourlabel  will have the value that you ve passed. So then you can use something like self.after to update a func every 1000 ms.

Comment: I just wanted to know how to update a tkintergui, but thanks for the reply.

Answer (score -2):

You are updating just the variable value, not the value of the label.
You need to update the label with the content of c after increasing it:

```
Text.configure(text=c)
```

So it becomes something like that:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

c = 0
root = Tk()
root.title("Real Time Plot")
root.minsize(width = 200, height = 300)
m = root.winfo_reqwidth() / 2

root.update()
Text = Label(root, text = c)
Text.place(x =m, y = 150)
root.update()

time.sleep(2)
c = c + 1
Text.configure(text=c)
root.update()

print(m)

root.mainloop()
```

I did some minor update to your code, like adding a sleep time, to better show the behaviour.

Comment: Not Working. The value changes from `0` to `1` and it stops there.

Comment: The OP wrote "**Only the update** is a problem, maybe someone can help me with **that**". The provided code **updates** the value and clearly explains how to do it.  So maybe you should be more careful when commenting to solutions provided by others.

Comment: Talking about OP, he clearly stated a word **Realtime** which I am sure u missed. Also, he said to _place the Label according to the width of the root_ which also you missed. Then, maybe **you** should be careful to read the problem, or atleast make a working code

Comment: Thank y'all for the fast reply. @Samaksh Gupta, i looked at your Code, and i found an alternative for the width and height problem: ```root_height = root.winfo_height()
        root_height = int(root_height)``` Only possible with the help of your code, thank you :)